# Why don't my node hover popups work in my vis.js network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am having an issue where despite including the 'title' property in my node objects, when I hover over a node, no pop up window with the contents of my title are displayed.

Here are my options and how I set my network up.

```
setUpNetwork(){
    let container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
    //These options dictate the dynamic of the network
    let options = {
        nodes: {
            shape: 'box'
        },
        interaction: {
            dragNodes: false,
            dragView: false,
            hover: true
        },
        layout: {
            randomSeed: undefined,
            improvedLayout: true,
            hierarchical: {
                enabled: true,
                levelSeparation: 180,
                nodeSpacing: 180,
                edgeMinimization: true,
                parentCentralization: true,
                direction: 'UD', // UD, DU, LR, RL
                sortMethod: 'directed' // hubsize, directed
            }
        },
        physics: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
    // initialize your network!
    this.network = new vis.Network(container, this.data, options);
}
```

When I add a node to my list of nodes for my network, this is my structure:

```
addNode(node: any){
    try {
        this.data.nodes.add({
            id: node.id,
            color: node.color,
            title: node.title,
            label: node.label
        });
        this.network.fit();
    }
    catch (err) {}
}
```

The environment that I'm running my code from makes it difficult to provide an example of this issue live. Everything else in the network works just fine (label, id, color), just not the title when I hover over a node.

**EDIT**:

I copied this code from [this example](http://visjs.org/examples/network/events/interactionEvents.html) from vis.js where pop ups are working.

```
// create an array with nodes
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, label: 'Node 1', title: 'I have a popup!'},
    {id: 2, label: 'Node 2', title: 'I have a popup!'},
    {id: 3, label: 'Node 3', title: 'I have a popup!'},
    {id: 4, label: 'Node 4', title: 'I have a popup!'},
    {id: 5, label: 'Node 5', title: 'I have a popup!'}
]);

// create an array with edges
var edges = new vis.DataSet([
    {from: 1, to: 3},
    {from: 1, to: 2},
    {from: 2, to: 4},
    {from: 2, to: 5}
]);

// create a network
var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
};
var options = {interaction:{hover:true}};
this.network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

I tried using only this in my environment; however, the popups don't show up like in the example. I know my hovering event works because I included this code to print to console when I hover over a node:

```
this.network.on("showPopup", function (params) {
    console.log("DO SOMETHING");
})
```

Is there some options setting that I'm missing here? Could there be some other issue as to why my hover popups don't show despite including the "title" property in my node objects?

Comment: were you able to solve the problem? I am also facing the same issue. Please help

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is showing because you are using event on("showPopup"). You have to use on("hoverNode"). So use

```
network.on("hoverNode", function(){
  // functionality for popup to show on mouseover
});


network.on("blurNode", function(){
  // functionality for popup to hide on mouseout
});
```

For adding nodes its better to use

```
nodes.add()
```

Comment: Title should be shown without using these on hover functions as we are defining title. But it is not showing. Not sure what's the issue. Stuck at same kind of problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue.  In my case it was a css issue.  Make sure you import vis.min.css correcly.  I had a typo in the link statement.

Comment: Where can I find this file, `vis.min.css`?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you might not be importing the vis-network CSS.
You can import the standalone version of vis-network and it will automatically import the CSS.

```
import { Network } from 'vis-network/standalone';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the CSS

```
.vis-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
  }
```

Otherwise the tooltip while appearing is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever looking for the solution, place the `vis-network.min.js` in a directory and call like this.

```
<script>
            type="text/javascript"
            src="vis-network.min.js"
        </script>
```

you download the `vis-network.min.js` from [example](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/events/interactionEvents.html) . Got to the inspect element and then sources tab. The file is under `standalone/umd`